# "Reference Request" for a lecture note by C. Skinner: Galois Representations, Iwasawa Theory, and Special Values of $L$-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

*This was originally posted on math.stackexchange as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589793, where I was suggested to move it here.*

I'm searching a lecture note by C. Skinner named **"Galois Representations, Iwasawa Theory, and Special Values of $L$-functions"**.

The only related source that I am able to found is the following link in *semantic scholar*:
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/GALOIS-REPRESENTATIONS%2C-IWASAWA-THEORY%2C-AND-SPECIAL-Skinner/de5b0042a09693f7fa2f80b573c20fc41395e823

Unfortunately, the link provided there ([https://www.math.ias.edu/~pwake/seminar/skinner.pdf](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Epwake/seminar/skinner.pdf)) is dead. I found the webpage of P. Wake (https://sites.google.com/msu.edu/prestonwake/research), who has now moved to Michigan, but I haven't found the note there either.

**So could anyone provide an accessible link to the note**? Thank you so much!

Its abstract reads:

> These notes are an elaboration on lectures given during the third week of the 2009 Clay Mathematics Institute summer school on Galois representations. These lectures, in conjunction with lectures given by Joël Beläıche [Bel09], attempted to explain how Galois representations have been used to prove results in the direction of the Bloch-Kato conjectures for values of L-functions. The topics covered in the author’s lectures mostly related to Iwasawa theory and the exploitation of the Galois representations associated with automorphic representations (or families thereof) in the proofs of instances of the Iwasawa-Greenberg Main Conjectures and their concomitant consequences for special value formulas